# jQuery droppable ignore the z-index?

Tags: jquery

My problem, the drop-function starts when I sort the list.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function rt()
{
    $("#div1").draggable();
    $("#k1").sortable({ revert: '100' });
    $('#droparea').droppable({ accept: 'li', drop: function() { alert('ssss'); } });
});
```

**html**

```
 <div id="div1" style="z-index:5;">
    <ul id="k1" style="width:350px; height:200px; background-color:#ffffff; margin:20px; padding:10px; border:1px solid #000000; ">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="droparea" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#cccccc; z-index:1;"></div>
```

Working example

http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/130/

Tabks in advance.
Peter

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do or what's failing.

Comment: Hi D Hoerster, the drop-function starts when i sort the list. But i only want to start the drop when i drop something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your question title is misleading - `z-index` is a CSS property that decides which element would display on top of each other when two or more of them occupy the same space, and has nothing to do with the problem you are having here.

The solution to your problem is rather easy: make the `div` containing the list droppable, then use the greedy option to prevent the `drop` event from bubbling up.

Have a look here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/DKZRp/1/